# Evaluate $\iint_D xy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

My question is, evaluate the area under the curve, $\iint_D xy$, where $D$ is a region bounded by $y=\sin(x)$ and $y=\cos(x)$. Here is an illustration of it:

[image]

As you can see, $D$ is the area between the 2 functions. If I can find the boundaries for the $x$ and $y$ values then we are done. But I cannot determine the $x$ and $y$ values because they seem to be arbitrary. So I need another way to find the integral. I can try converting to polar coordinates, $y=\cos x=r\sin\theta=\sin x$. $xy=r\cos\theta r\cos\theta$. But how would I find the boundaries in terms of polar coordinates?

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly is your difficulty in finding the bounds for $D$? The most difficult step to recollection would just be ascertaining when $\sin(x) = \cos(x)$, no?

Comment: $\iint_D xy \, dxdy$ is *not* “the area under the curve”!

Comment: @Prometheus: That would give $\iint_D dxdy$, not $\iint_D x y \, dxdy$.

Comment: Ah, the lack of a $dx$ or $dy$ made me think it was a typo. @HansLundmark

Comment: @Prometheus: Well, actually who knows? Maybe $xy$ was supposed to be $dxdy$ to begin with? But dropping $dx$ and $dy$ is probably a more common mistake than just dropping $d$ and $d$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sin(x)=\cos(x)$ when $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi$ thus your integral becomes

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5}{4}\pi}x\left[\int_{\cos(x)}^{\sin(x)} y dy   \right]dx$$

I think you can easy solve these integrals without difficulty. As you can see, no polars are needed.